# Content Script doesn't run until page reload

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, web-extension

Although there are a lot of similar questions here, I couldn't solve my problem with any of the accepted solutions, so I'm creating a new question.

I have a content script that adds some functionality to a [Jira Issue](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-13783).
However, when navigating to the Jira Issue from a [Filter Results Page](https://jira.atlassian.com/projects/SRCTREEWIN/issues/SRCTREEWIN-13783?filter=allissues), the content script doesn't run until I manually reload the page.

What I've tried so far:

1. Adding [webNavigation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation) Listeners (with the manifest permission), but none of them seem to trigger when the Jira Issue link is clicked from the Filter Page.

```
// background.js

const myLog = () => console.log('webNavigation event triggered');

browser.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(myLog);
browser.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(myLog);
browser.webNavigation.onReferenceFragmentUpdated.addListener(myLog);
```

2. Adding **"all_frames": true** to the manifest.json, but that didn't make it work either:

```
// manifest.json

...

"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://jira.atlassian.com/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
"permissions": ["tabs", "webNavigation", "<all_urls>"]
```

3. Listening to **window.onpopstate** event inside the content script. Although it detects when I click the "Back" and "Forward" arrows in the browser, it doesn't fire when I click the links inside the [Filter Results Page](https://jira.atlassian.com/projects/SRCTREEWIN/issues/SRCTREEWIN-13783?filter=allissues).

```
// content.js

window.onpopstate = () => {
 browser.runtime.sendMessage('webNavigation event triggered');
}
```

How can I run this content script without having to manually reload the page?

Comment: webNavigation listeners should be triggered so you probably look in the [wrong console](/q/38913799). It's easier to use chrome.tabs.onUpdated though. See also [this answer](/a/39508954) for more info.

Comment: @wOxxOm mmm it doesn't seem to be the wrong console. Maybe the problem has to do with the fact that the URL itself doesn't change, the page is just re-rendered but the URL is the same. I've tried the pjax:end and the hashchange options but it didn't work either. MutationObservers work, but they seem a bit hacky...

Comment: MutationObserver is the right tool, conceptually and practically, if the URL doesn't change.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you! Then [this answer of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener/39508954#39508954) is more than enough to deal with this problem.